# VSC Remote SSH - How to fix reconnection problems?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote-ssh

When using VSC Remote SSH, I am constantly getting the error `"Cannot reconnect. Please reload the window."`. Upon clicking "Reload Window", the window reloads and I receive the same error.

Sometimes I am also getting the following notification: `"The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (forkpty(3) failed)."`

More errors showing here:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0I5j.png)

I tried to find the solution but nothing worked for me, any suggestions? I tried:

- Reinstalling extension
- Deleting the VS Code + cache directory on the server
- Restarting server

**Update 17-01:** Today it worked fine for around 2 hours. It randomly stopped working while I was typing a few lines of code without doing something else like saving, adding or delete files. The message is still te same and did not found any solution yet.

Comment: Why don't mount it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest update 1.82 borked this too. Uninstalling WSL extension fixed it and restart vscode. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192646

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue recently, for me it looks like disabling the [wix.vs-code.import-cost](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost) extension remedied the issue.

This is probably because I am using private registries for npm packages and that could easily cause issues if attempting to load the private modules from any public source, but I didn't really look into it, so this is just my best guess.